# Copy a portion of an NSMutableData to a new NSMutableData object

Tags: swift, macos, nsdata

I am reading in a large file into an NSMutableData object.

```
var lBuffer : NSMutableData = try NSMutableData(contentsOfFile: pFilePath)
```

I would like to get a portion of the NSMutableData object to work with at a time.  So I am trying to use .subdata(with: NSRange), but am getting an error.

```
var lBufferChunk : NSMutableData = lBuffer.subdata(with: NSRange(location: 0, length: lSizeOfChunk)) as! NSMutableData
```

The error I get is:
Could not cast value of type 'NSSubrangeData' (0x7fffa6ea3ef8) to 'NSMutableData' (0x7fffa6a403f8)

According to the documentation, .subdata(with: NSRange) should return a Data object.

How can I get it to a Data object to cast it back to NSMutableData?  Or is there a better way of getting a portion/fragment out of a large NSMutableData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to, you could cast the result of calling `lBuffer.subdata` to an NSData and then call `mutableCopy()` and force-cast the result to NSMutableData. But don't! Don't even use NSData or NSMutableData in the first place. This is Swift. Use Data.

```
var lBuffer = Data(contentsOf: myFileURL)
```

Now just call `subdata(in:)`

```
var lBufferChunk = lBuffer.subdata(in: myRange)
```

Or subscript

```
var lBufferChunk = lBuffer[myRange]
```

The `var` makes it mutable.

Comment: or simply `lBuffer[myRange]`

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to use NSMutableData is because I need to pass it to an objective-c function that takes in a NSMutableData object.

Comment: What a strange function that would be! But if that's really the case, you can pass a Data to that function as I already explained. For example to pass `lBufferChunk` where an NSMutableData is expected you would do what I already said: cast it to NSData and then call `mutableCopy()` and force-cast to NSMutableData.

Answer (score 0):

So, I went a different route to solve my issue.  As you can see, I wanted to read in a file to a NSMutableData object, but wanted to copy smaller portions of it at a time (in the case of large files).  Instead of reading a range of one Data object and passing it to the other, I decided to use an input stream instead.

```
var lInputStream : InputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: pFilePath)!
var lBuffer : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: lBufferSize)
lInputStream.open()
while lInputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
     let read = lInputStream.read(lBuffer, maxLength: lBufferSize)
     var dataChunk = NSMutableData(length: 0)
     dataChunk?.append(lBuffer, length: read)

     ...

}
lInputStream.close()
```

Matt's answer is correct for the way the question was originally asked and I've marked it as so.  Just wanted to share what I ended up doing in the end.